# Why can't auto be used as a template type parameter?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I've been playing around with C++0x's `auto` keyword and tried the following.

```
std::unique_ptr<auto> ptr(new int(0));
```

I tried compiling it with g++ 4.4.5 and got

```
error: invalid use of auto
```

Judging by eye, `auto` can easily be inferred to `int`.

My guess is the type inference and the template engine don't talk to each other. Otherwise, the template engine would know to instantiate the template class with `int` as the type parameter.

Another guess is from the standard, I see this.

```
A member shall not be declared with auto, extern or register storage class.
```

But I thought that was the `auto` as in local variables, not as in `auto` used to deduce types.

And my last guess is that the compiler thinks this is an `auto` storage class, not `auto` for type deduction.

Is there a reason behind this stated in the standard?

Comment: Note: that quote "a member shall not..." is not from C++0X. `auto` is not a storage class specifier in that standard. N3290: "A member shall not be declared with the extern or register storage-class-speciﬁer."

Comment: It could also be `std::unique_ptr<int[]> ptr(new int(0));`, so your proof of concept is wrong.

Comment: @GMan: Are you sure. Note it is a single value.

Comment: @Martin: Both `std::unique_ptr<int>` and `std::unique_ptr<int[]>` have a constructor taking an `int*`. Note that even `new int[100000000]` still just looks like an `int*` after the fact. This problem is fundamental to the language. The solution would require arrays truly be there own type, so dynamically allocated arrays would be an array type, not a pointer type. And this is just talking about `std::unique_ptr<auto>(...)`, who knows about the general case of the problem.

Comment: Hold on! I may be getting this wrong. But does not: `std::unique_ptr<int[]>` calls `delete[]` while `std::unique_ptr<int>` calls `delete`

Comment: @GMan, Good point. So if we pretend we could prove that this is the most general case of the problem, then it's possible for the compiler to just spit out an "ambiguous type inference" error, just like ambiguous overloads right?

Comment: @Martin: Right, but that has nothing to do with what `auto` should be. `int*` as a type carries no information on how it ought to be deleted, after all.

Comment: @Russell: Right. In very specific cases it might be able to deduce it, but for most generic cases it won't be able to. Adding such machinery to the language isn't worth the cost, if it only works some of the time.

Comment: The `auto` keyword does not define a type, but a storage classification.  The `unique_ptr` requires a type, not a storage class.  This is like stating: `std::unique_ptr<static>`.

Comment: @Thomas : That's true in C++03, but not C++0x.

Comment: @GMan: OK. I see what you are getting at. Basically auto in this situation can not automatically detect the type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@dascandy has correctly identified what's wrong with your code.  I'll try to provide some rationale:

You're expecting the compiler to infer `unique_ptr<int>` because the argument is an `int*`, and `unique_ptr<int>` has a constructor which accepts `int*`.  For a moment let's ignore the fact that we're using `std::unique_ptr`, and just talk about a template class we wrote (and can specialize).

Why should the compiler infer `unique_ptr<int>`?  The argument isn't `int`, it's `int*`.  Why shouldn't it guess `unique_ptr<int*>`?  Of course that would result in a compiler error, since `unique_ptr<int*>`'s constructor won't accept an `int*`.  Unless I add a specialization:

```
template<>
class unique_ptr<int*>
{
public:
    unique_ptr(int*) {}
};
```

Now `unique_ptr<int*>` would compile.  How should the compiler know which to choose, `unique_ptr<int>` or `unique_ptr<int*>`?  What if I add another specialization?

```
template<>
class unique_ptr<double>
{
public:
    unique_ptr(int*) {}
};
```

The compiler now has three options to choose from, and it has to instantiate the template with every possible argument in order to find them.  Clearly this is not feasible, especially with multiple template arguments and template recursion.

What you can do, is make a factory function which connects the inferred type to exactly one template instance:

```
template<typename T>
std::unique_ptr<T> make_unique(T* arg) { return arg; }
```

(of course, this won't work because `unique_ptr` cannot be copied.  But the idea is valid, and used in e.g.`make_shared` and `make_pair`.)

---

Some examples of extreme ugliness:

One could argue that `unique_ptr<shared_ptr<int>>` is a valid match for this code.

Or how about:

```
template<typename T>
class unique_ptr
{
public:
    explicit unique_ptr(T* arg);
    unique_ptr(int*, enable_if<(sizeof(T) > 16)>::type* = 0);
};
```

Comment: "and it has to instantiate the template with every possible argument in order to find them" No, because it already knows what specializations exist. That said, it's ambiguous in the general case, as two specializations could each have template constructors, so neither is preferable. It's doable for some class templates, but I suspect it would only work some of the time in the general case. If a complex feature should be added to the language, it should work most or all of the time; so like you said, too complex to be feasible.

Comment: `template<typename T> std::unique_ptr<T> make_unique(T* arg) { return std::unique_ptr<T>(arg); }` would work just fine, since `unique_ptr` is movable (but its constructor is `explicit`).

Comment: @GMan: Consider partial specialization and template recursion... the number of specializations potentially introduced is unbounded.  What about a template using `enable_if` and a type trait?  In the general case, the compiler has to instantiate with every possible argument.

Comment: @Ben: There's still always a finite number of specializations to check. If that weren't the case the compiler wouldn't be able to process them at all.

Comment: @GMan: Right now, there's a finite number of specializations to check, because the template argument is provided by the programmer.

Comment: @Dennis: Thanks, I did have a mismash.  The one remaining reference to `shared_ptr` is intentional.

Comment: @Ben: I'm not sure I understand. Given `T<auto> x(y);`, `T` is a class template. (If it's not, we get an error). Given a class template, the compiler may have also parsed some specializations of that class template, and has them in a list as well. This is how it instantiates `T<U>`, after all: what `U` fits best? Now back to our problem of deducing `U`, though, the compiler just needs to check each one; a finite number of cases (or even explicit `U`'s would fail). In most cases, generally, this should result in ambiguity. But there's nothing infinite about the problem.

Comment: @GMan: Template constructors not required to introduce ambiguity, as you pointed out yourself `unique_ptr<int[]>`.

Comment: @GMan: How are there a finite number of possible `U`s?  It could be `int`.  It could be `shared_ptr<int>`.  It could be `std::complex<double>`.  Explicit usage works because the work associated with testing a single `U` is feasible, not because the number of `U` candidates is bounded.

Comment: @Ben: Again, I didn't say finite number of `U`'s, I said finite number of specializations. You *can* deduce `U` in this case, even though there are an infinite number of them: `template <typename T> struct id { id(T); }; id<U>(5); // zero specializations; base case has single constructor; constructor argument is T; T is U; 5 is int; T is int; U is int;`, because we only have to check the base class and specializations. Maybe I should state it this way: the algorithm always halts, given that it can either output `U`'s type or "ambiguous".

Comment: @GMan: How would that work with the last code snippet in my answer?

Comment: It couldn't, as you've effectively introduced a template constructor. So it would return "ambiguous".

Comment: @GMan: And what if it were `enable_if<(2 * sizeof (T) == 3)>`?  That constructor won't be enabled for ANY `T`, so it can't make the problem ambiguous, but it can defeat inference.  Of course we already have non-deducible contexts for functions, but here we have them with more degrees of freedom.

Comment: @Ben: I'm not sure what you're trying to prove to me. I've already stated multiple times it's undecidable in the general case. The only thing I've objected to is the phrase "and it has to instantiate the template with every possible argument in order to find them". It can work from the inside-out, which is finite, and not the outside-in, which is "infinite".

Comment: @GMan: If you're willing to skip cases where there are potentially unbounded matches, then the problem remains tractable.  But you aren't saying "inference succeeded" or "ambiguous", you're saying "inference succeeded", "ambiguous", or "non-deducible in this context, searching for matches is intractable".  Just because a particular case has unbounded search effort doesn't mean that multiple matches would be found, so it isn't necessarily ambiguous.

Comment: @GMan: Anyway, thanks for explaining how to reasonably approach this in the same subset of cases where deduction would be allowed for a free function.  I hadn't thought that part through.

Answer (score 10):

That's because it has to determine the class on which to call a constructor *before* determining what to do with its arguments. If you make the constructor a template, it'll just work like any other template function - auto-deducing arguments.

Comment: Correct -- type deduction doesn't work for template classes.  Usually you end up using a factory function as a workaround, e.g. `auto ptr(make_unique(new int(0)));`

Answer (score 2):

Just want to add that a solution already exists for most cases:

```
template <typename T>
std::unique_ptr<T> unique_ptr_auto(T* ptr)
{
    // fails to handle std::unique_ptr<T[]>, not deducible from pointer
    return std::unique_ptr<T>(ptr);
}

auto ptr = unique_ptr_auto(new int(0));
```

A bit more verbose, obviously, but you get the idea. These "generator functions" are quite common.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: No, it isn't, but it doesn't have to be for this particular code sample to operate correctly.

Answer (score 2):

This (or similar) *was* proposed for the Standard. The proposed functionality looked something like:

```
std::vector<int> GetMahVector();
std::vector<auto> var = GetMahVector();
```

However, it was rejected. Why it was rejected, well, you'd have to dig up the relevant Standard process documents, if possible.

Comment: Ah, so it is actually documented somewhere. Thank you!

Comment: This restricted version wouldn't be very useful, you can already say `auto var = GetMahVector();`

Comment: @BenVoigt would definitely be useful for redability in some case

Comment: The current proposal (for C++17) for this syntax is http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4377.pdf . The proposal contains a whole of things all related to templates, but this syntax is buried in there as well.